# Afnetworking Get method error unauthorized (401)

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking-2

I'm getting this response in error.userInfo while making a Get request from AFNetworking.

```
  "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo=0x17d296c0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://futstepz.node.com/emap/api/v1/users/friend_list_page?auth_token=xyz, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17d9f5e0> { URL:http://futstepz.node.com/emap/api/v1/users/friend_list_page?auth_token=xyz } { status code: 401, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 74;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 10 Sep 2014 06:42:27 GMT";
    Server = "WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.2/2014-05-08)";
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
    "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
    "X-Request-Id" = "51544d50-3d1b-4b54-b8c9-34540b73e695";
    "X-Runtime" = "0.007077";
    "X-Ua-Compatible" = "chrome=1";
    "X-Xss-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401)}
```

And I'm using this code;

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];


[manager GET:@"http://futstepz.node.com/emap/api/v1/users/friend_list_page?auth_token=xyz" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
```

Comment: i suggest you test your request with cURl. seems like server is rejected the request which could be for a number of reasons such as missing http header, bad auth code etc...

Comment: what is this cURL? whether 401 error occurs due to credentails? In browser when i paste the link its working

Comment: see [guide](http://httpkit.com/resources/HTTP-from-the-Command-Line/)

Comment: i have tested with cURL, its working fine

Comment: did you get this fixed?

Comment: Any answer to this? I would like to know

Comment: All of a sudden I'm in the same boat. With postman all request works but with iPhone one out of two requests work. The two requests only differ by URL. Though server is same.